# Obtain Storm Topology Stats programmatically

Tags: apache-storm

I am building a monitoring service around my Storm topology, and would like to be able to obtain the number of failed tuples around various time windows, similar to how the Storm UI shows number of failed tuples in a 10m, 3h, and 1d window.

My monitoring service is currently built in python, so it would appreciated if the answer involves either a python library or something language agnostic, like shelling out to a CLI or hitting a REST endpoint. I took a look at the Storm CLI as well as the docs, but so far have come up empty handed with regards to where the Storm UI is actually obtaining the information from.

EDIT:
- Running storm version 0.8.2(unfortunately out of my control), so the storm-ui-rest-api(released in 0.9.2) is unfortunately not an option until an upgrade effort is made.

Answer (score 5):

Use the storm [UI Rest API](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/STORM-UI-REST-API.md)

```
sqlInjection@foo:~$ curl http://$STORM_UI_HOST_AND_PORT/api/v1/topology/summary
```

> {"topologies":[{"id":"topology-1-1436004781","encodedId":"topology-1-1436004781","encodedId","name":"topology-1","status":"ACTIVE","uptime":"40d
>   21h 51m 59s","tasksTotal":16,"workersTotal":1,"executorsTotal":10}]}

```
sqlInjection@foo:~$ curl http://$STORM_UI_HOST_AND_PORT/api/v1/topology/topology-1-1436004781
```

> {"msgTimeout":30,"spouts":[{"executors":3,"emitted":22336820,"errorLapsedSecs":755996,"completeLatency":"232.052","transferred":22336820,"acked":22340300,"errorPort":6703,"spoutId":"KafkaSpout-removed","tasks":3,"errorHost":"removed","lastError":"java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat
>   backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128)\n\tat
>   backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatch(Di","errorWorkerLogLink":"http://host:port/log?file=worker-6703.log","failed":0,"encodedSpoutId":"KafkaSpout-removed"}],"executorsTotal":8,"uptime":"67d
>   21h 15m
>   2s","encodedId":"topology-1-1436004781","visualizationTable":[{":row":[{":stream":"default",":sani-stream":"default1544803905",":checked":true},{":stream":"__ack_init",":sani-stream":"s__ack_init973324006",":checked":false},{":stream":"__ack_ack",":sani-stream":"s__ack_ack1278315507",":checked":false},{":stream":"__ack_fail",":sani
>   ... removed

As you can see, you can even catch the last error that happened in your bolts/spouts.

Comment: This is a great answer, however, it only looks like it is available on Storm 0.9.2+, and unfortunately we are still only on 0.8.2.

Comment: Yeah :/ unfortunately those things aren't within my control.

Comment: [Working link for REST API](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/0.10.x-branch/STORM-UI-REST-API.md), unfortunately not available from master

Answer (score 0):

I use python get this, if the "failed" too highly will restart the topology

```
pid = urllib2.urlopen('http://'+host+':'+port+'/api/v1/topology/summary').read()
    data_pid = json.loads(pid)
    for data in data_pid['topologies']:
        if data['name'] == '':
            print 'no topology'
            break
        elif data['name'] == topology_name:
            url_pid = data['id'].encode("UTF-8")
            break
    content = urllib2.urlopen('http://'+host+':'+port+'/api/v1/topology/'+url_pid).read()
    data_content = json.loads(content)
    if data_content['topologyStats'][0]['failed'] == None:
            data_content['topologyStats'][0]['failed'] = 0
    if data_content['topologyStats'][0]['acked'] == None:
            data_content['topologyStats'][0]['acked'] = 0
    if data_content['topologyStats'][0]['acked'] < data_content['topologyStats'][0]['failed']*10:
            global count
            count  = count + 1
            if count == 2:
                    os.system("monit restart "+ monitor_name)
                    logger.info('restart at '+ time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(time.time())))
                    count = 0
```

if you want to know more,
http://chenshuxiang.applinzi.com/index.php/2017/09/13/storm-ui/